# Why nth-child to add style to alternate visible element not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on adding style to **Alternate Visible Elements**. Initially i thought of using `nth-child(2n+1)` idea, but apparently it doesn't works!. To boil down my problem, below is the sample:

HTML:

```
<div class='hide find'>TEST</div>
<div class='hide find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='hide find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='hide find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='hide find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='hide find'>TEST</div> 
<div class='find'>TEST</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
.alternate{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.find:visible:nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('alternate');    //This is not working! Why?
```

I am not sure of what is the reason of failure. Although, I did some workaround on the problem and created a function, which works, but it would be smooth and better, if the problem can be resolved using the above approach. Below is the workaround i made it to work:

```
function addAlternateStyle(){
var alt= true;
    $('.find:visible').each(function(){
        if(alt){
            alt=!alt;
            $(this).addClass('alternate');
        }
        else{
            alt=!alt;
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use list element to give alternative style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:-

```
$('.find:visible:even').addClass('alternate');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lsuv8fd/)

Comment: nth-chiild not work in that way it will access all elements even they are hide or visible.

Comment: Strange behavior! Input to `nth-child` is from `.find:visible`. Ideally it should take that list..

Answer (score 1):

You can select the odd/even elements in your selection using this jQuery formulas:

```
$('div[class!="hide find"]:even')  

$('div[class!="hide find"]:odd')
```

I used the odd/even pseudo class and checked the visibility using a "not" selector (class != "hide find")